# How to insulate a high voltage PCB trace?

Tags: high-voltage, insulation

I am making a PCB with a HV power supply module. Namely the C9619 module from Hamamatsu. The module produces up to 2 mA and 4 W of power so the heat won't be a problem

The module can produce up to 2000 volts, but I will be using it at around 1000 volts and it will deliver a current of around 400 \$ \mu \$A.

What insulator do you recommend to place above the high voltage copper traces?

Comment: You can use Saturn PCB toolkit to calculate isolation distances. http://www.saturnpcb.com/pcb_toolkit/  At 1000V you need at least 5mm isolation distance if the traces run in the outer layers. If the PCB is covered by solder resist the isolation distance is reduced to ~2.33mm

Comment: For compliance to EN60950 (IT Equipment) the creepage/clearance requirement is 8.4mm (up to 2.8kV) and you don't need additional insulation.  What is you application as this may not be the standard you need to work too.  Also details should be in the question and not comments.

Comment: PCB cutouts will be your fiend here to meet creepage requirements.

Comment: Removing FOUR WATTS of heat can be a problem. The thermal resistance of 1 square of standard-thickness copper foil is 70 degree Centigrade per watt. You have 70 * 4 = 280 degree Centigrade heating challenge.